# How to filter product with related product?

Tags: filter, magento-1.7, product

I have to create filter option, which is related product. But I am not getting an idea about it. I have attach image url for reference. Here are product listing, which are related product. And I have to use related product in filter option

http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/5201307260938309_Capture.PNG

Please help me asap.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to define a new product attribute to filter by. You could do a multiselect with all the potential related products and set `Use In Layered Navigation` to `Yes`.

Comment: I have create 'product' attribute. But How can I fetch all related product in multiselect option.?